# what is equivalent of Oracle's Bulk Collect in DB2

Tags: database, oracle, db2

I have to return result set from Db2 to java program. result set have millions of rows. Is there something like bulk fetch of oracle in DB2.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Db2 supports mult-row fetch for scrollable cursors. Check [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_c0052058.html).

However, with millions of rows, it still may be inefficient compared to alternative approaches. Consider doing unload/export (depending on your Db2-server operating-system), and depending on what you want to do with the result-set, and how often you want to do this action.